# for one UIView, do two animations, one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a `UIView` called *myView*. First, move it to the left. Then move it to the right. I used two `[UIView animatedWithDuration:delay:animations:^completed:^]`. But it didn't work.

I asked a senior engineer and he gave me this solution.

```
[UIView animatedWithDuration:
                  animations:
                          //first animation
                  completed:
                          dispatch_after(.....){
                              //second animation
                          }
]
```

By using the dispatch_after(), the two animations can be execuated sequentially.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    self.theView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        self.theView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 10, 100, 100);
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. But if the logic is very complex, the code will be highly nested. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the complex logic? can you describe more?

Comment: This is what I do when i want to chain two animations and it works like a charm. :)